Minimal generator systems of a finitely generated

Let $A$ a local commutative ring with unity and $M$ an $A$-module. If $M$ is finitely generated, its minimal generator systems have the same cardinal.

I am trying to prove this claim in order to use it on another, but I am getting stuck. My intuition says that it should be a way to use the Nakayama's lemma with $\mu \subset A$ the unique maximal ideal of $A$, but I am not seeing how exactly do it, I also have tried to take $S_1, S_2 \subset M$ minimal generator systems and construct a bijection between them but I am struggling with it, so any possible help would be appreciated.

I can't just comment since I do not have enough reputation ... but here is a thought :  $\{m_1,\ldots,m_n\}$ generate $M$ if and only if the images of these elements in $\overline{M}:= M/\mathfrak{m}M$ span $\overline{M}$
(Nakayama Lemma)... thus a minimal generating set of $M$ over $A$ contains $n = dim_k \overline{M}$ elements where $k = A/\mathfrak{m}$, $\mathfrak{m} \subset A$ being the maximal ideal...

Thanks for your answer! If I am not misunderstunding, since $\mu$ is maximal ideal, $A/\mu$ is a field and then $M/ \mu M$ is a vectorial space, so there the minimal generator systems can be taken WLOG as basis and two basis are of the same cardinality. Is this what you suggest?

Yes that's right
